# Apache + php7.2-fpm: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: server, apache2, php, phpmyadmin, webmin

I'm using Ubuntu (server) 18.04 LTS, Apache 2.4.29.
I have installed "Webmin" on my server.
I've enabled HTTP/2 on my server following the tutorial [How to Enable Apache HTTP2 on Ubuntu Linux](https://techexpert.tips/wordpress/how-to-enable-http2-apache-ubuntu-linux/).

So I have disabled `php7.2` (`a2dismod php7.2`) in order to make HTTP/2 work.

Now my virtualhost (created with VirtualMin) works as I want: php script works well and using http/2 protocol.

The problem is that on the machine, php files gives 503 error (while before following the tutorial, they work as expected), so for example a phpinfo file or phpmyadmin of the whole servers is not usable.

Looking at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I have the following:

```
[Fri Aug 30 15:28:24.994748 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 31372:tid 139674947397376] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock (*) failed

[Fri Aug 30 15:28:24.994773 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 31372:tid 139674947397376] [client 84.221.16.21:63483] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

Looks like a `php7.2-fpm` socket problem.

Someone know how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you fix this ??

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this solved it:

```
service php7.2-fpm start
systemctl enable php7.2-fpm
```